# Permutation problem with ordering persons in a line

Tags: probability, permutations

We have the following problem:

There are $p$ persons from each city. Consider $p \cdot n$ persons from $n$ different cities. The $p \cdot n$ persons stand in a line such that every person stands next to a person from the same city.

Prove that the number of ways that this can be done is:

$\displaystyle (p!)^n \cdot \sum _{k=0} ^n (-1)^k \cdot \binom {n} {k} \cdot  (2n-k)!$

I know that it's something with the inclusion-exclusion theorem, but I don't know how.

The $(2n-k)!$ term in the summation is for me a big question.

Comment: is it necessary that the person on both sides must be of the same city?

Comment: @ADG: No, only on one side

Comment: @ADG: I don't see how that would possible, since that would mean that everyone in the line would have to be from the same city.  They must merely have one neighbor from the same city.  This condition is the same as requiring that the people be arranged so that they can be divided into intervals of at least two (but possibly more) people from the same city.  For instance, if the cities are $A, B, C, D, \ldots$, then a permissible sequence would be $A, A, A, B, B, C, C, C, C, D, D$, but $A, A, A, B, C, C, C, D, D, D$ would not be permissible, because of the singleton $B$.